# How to connect a button action handler and GUI to the rest of my code?

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

So right now, my project is almost done. All I need to do is get my button to fire my code that does all the non-GUI work. Can anyone take a look and give me any advice?

Basically, I know the back end works and I know the GUI works. I need to bridge them together, which I assume will be through the button click. I can't seem to get the button click to save the info as the program doesn't seem to recognize certain variables in the WorkOut() section, as it doesn't seem to like getSelectedItem(), which stops me from testing to see if the actual workout will start and run

```
 package Final;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application; 
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene; 
import javafx.scene.control.*; 
import javafx.scene.layout.*; 
import javafx.stage.Stage; 
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class FinalGUI extends Application { 

    // launch the application 
    public void start(Stage stage) { 

        try { 

            // set title for the stage 
            stage.setTitle("Your Work Out Friend"); 

            // create a VBox 
            VBox vbox = new VBox(); 

            // create a label 
            Label label = new Label("Choose your muscle group and your workout goal."); 

            // Creates a list that the vbox can use
            ObservableList<String> choicesMuscle = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                "Chest day", "Back day", "Leg day");

            ObservableList<String> choicesRep = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                "Lose weight", "Gain muscle mass", "Gain Strength");

            // add label to vbox 
            vbox.getChildren().add(label); 

            // add buttons to VBox 
            vbox.getChildren().add(new ComboBox(choicesMuscle)); 
            vbox.getChildren().add(new ComboBox(choicesRep)); 
            Button btnOK = new Button();
            btnOK.setText("Give me a workout!");
            vbox.getChildren().add(btnOK);




            //Main issue results here, I need to save user input from the combo box and then use that
            //to compare to the selection tree in WorkOut()
            btnOK.setOnAction(a -> {
                WorkOut w = new WorkOut();
                Text Output = new Text();
                //TextArea text = new TextArea();
                //text.setPrefRowCount(10);
                //text.setPrefColumnCount(20);
                //text.setWrapText(true);
                //String cMuscle = (String) val.getSelectedItem();
                //String cRep = (String) choicesRep.getSelectedItem();
                w.muscleWorkOut();
                w.repWorkOut();
                Output.setText("Your workout is: " );
                //+ cRep + cMuscle
            });

            // create a scene 
            Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 350, 200); 

            // set the scene 
            stage.setScene(scene); 

            stage.show(); 
        } 

        catch (Exception e) { 

            System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
        } 
    } 

    // Main Method 
    public static void main(String args[]) { 

        // launch the application 
        launch(args); 
    } 



    public class WorkOut{

        private static final int range = 6;

        //Main Workout decision tree

        public void muscleWorkOut() {


            if (cMuscle.equalsIgnoreCase("Chest Day")) {
                printArray(chestDay());
            } 
            else if (cMuscle.equalsIgnoreCase("Leg Day")) {
                printArray(legDay());
            } 
            else if (cMuscle.equalsIgnoreCase("Back Day")) {
                printArray(backDay());
            } 
            else {
                System.out.println("Invalid choice made. Choose between Chest, Leg or Back days only.");
            }
        }

        public void repWorkOut(){
            if (cRep.equalsIgnoreCase("Lose Weight")) {
                /*output: 5 sets of 20 reps, in between reps 30 sec of Jump Rope,
                sprinting, or some form of high intensity cardio.
                */ 
                repChoice = "5 sets of 20 reps, with 1 minute of cardio in between";
            } 
            else if (cRep.equalsIgnoreCase("Gain muscle mass")) {
                //output: 4 sets of 10 reps, or 5 sets of 8 reps.
                repChoice = " 4 sets of 10 reps, or 5 sets of 8 reps";
            } 
            else if (cRep.equalsIgnoreCase("Gain strength")) {
                //output: 5sets of 3 reps, going up until you can't lift the weight
                repChoice = "5 sets of 3 reps, increasing the weight until you can no longer lift the weight.";
            } 
            else {
                System.out.println("Invalid choice made. Choose between the listed choices only.");
            }

    }

        public String[] backDay() {
            List<String> backList = new ArrayList <>();
            backList.add("Deadlift");
            backList.add("Pull Up");
            backList.add("Back Rows");
            backList.add("Bend-Over Barbell Rows");
            backList.add("Romanian Deadlift");
            backList.add("Front Squat");

            return randomizerHelper(backList);
        }

        public String[] chestDay() {
            List <String> chestList = new ArrayList <>();
            chestList.add("Bench Press");
            chestList.add("Incline Press");
            chestList.add("Dip");
            chestList.add("Flys");
            chestList.add("Reverse Flys");
            chestList.add("Supine Press");

            return randomizerHelper(chestList);
        }

        public String[] legDay() {
            List<String> legList = new ArrayList <>();
            legList.add("Squat");
            legList.add("Leg Press");
            legList.add("Leg Extension");
            legList.add("Dumbbell Step Up");
            legList.add("Body Weight Calf Raises");
            legList.add("Walking Lunge");

            return randomizerHelper(legList);
        }

        private String[] randomizerHelper(List<String> arr) {
            String[] returnArray = new String[3];
            String chosen;
            for(int i = 0; i < returnArray.length; i++) {
                chosen = arr.get((int) (Math.random() * range));

                for(int j = 0; j < returnArray.length; j++) {
                    if (!(chosen.equalsIgnoreCase(returnArray[j]))) {
                        returnArray[i]= chosen;
                        break; 
                    }
                }
            }
            return returnArray;
        }

        private void printArray(String[] arr) {
            for (String val : arr) {
                //need to change this into something else
                System.out.println(val);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure but it sounds and looks like you might have a Scope issue. Make sure that all the variables are declared in outer braces, not in different sets.

Also, when the button is clicked, you have to use get functions to obtain the values that the user entered before clicking submit.

Good Luck!